# Problem with launch file

Tags: roslaunch, rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 4 nodes that I want to launch at once.
The name of my package is robot_position and the name of launch file is abc.launch.
My launch file resides in a robot_position/launch.
When i run my launch file using `roslaunch robot_position abc`, following error appears:

```
[abc] is neither a launch file in package [robot_position] nor is [robot_position] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file.
```

Can anybody help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230044/problem-with-launch-file/) by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `roslaunch robot_position abc.launch`

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2016-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on 2016-03-24**:
Thank you, the problem is resolved! :)